# Can there be three significant pairwise interactions without a significant three-way interaction in a linear model?

Tags: r, interaction, linear-model

Given a response variable `y` and three predictors `A`, `B`, and `C`, can all predictors have significant pairwise interactive effects on `y` without having a three-way interactive effect on it? In other words, given the linear model (expressed in R notation):

`model1 <- lm(y ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + B:C + A:B:C)`

can `A:B`, `A:C`, and `B:C` have a significant effect on the variability of `y` without `A:B:C` having a significant effect on it?

Or, to phrase it once again differently: given the following alternative model without three-way interaction

`model2 <- lm(y ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + B:C)`

is it possible for `model1` to not have a residual variability that is significantly less than that of `model2` if `A:B`, `A:C`, and `B:C` all significantly contribute to reducing the residual variability of `model2`?

This question has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360430/moderation-two-way-interaction-different-across-groups-but-three-way-interacti), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298396/why-two-way-interaction-is-significant-but-three-way-interaction-is-not)) but, as far as I can tell, it has not been answered on this platform (although [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245239/in-three-way-anova-how-to-interpret-the-three-way-interaction) is relevant). I am posing the question in statistical terms but I believe it's more of a logical question.

Comment: Yes, of course. If the true coefficient of the product of A, B and C is 0, you would even hope to not get a significance here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple to simulate data and models to show that it is possible:

```
set.seed(1234)
# predictor values:
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
# simulated y values for a model with three pairwise interactions
# and no three-way interaction (x1*x2*x3):
y <- x1 + x2 + x3 + x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + rnorm(1000, 0, 10)

# a linear model which doesn't include a three-way interaction:
m1 <- lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3 + x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3)
summary(m1) # all are significant
# a linear model which does include a three-way interaction:
m2 <- lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3 + x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + x1*x2*x3)
summary(m2) # all but the 3-way interaction are significant
```

Comment: thanks! My intuition got in the way of my reasoning. I thought that, for some sort of transitive property, if x1*x2, x1*x3 and x2*x3 all had a significant effect on y, so should x1*x2*x3. I didn't think of running a simulation.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think that where you might have gotten this idea is from the reverse: If you include an interaction, many people (including me) think you have to include the main variables; if you include a 3 way interaction, you have to include all the 2 ways. 

David Rindskopf has written about some exceptions to this, but they are rare.